# Groovy complains unexpected token when evaluating relational operator on decimal values without leading zeroes

Tags: groovy

I am facing an issue with the execution of following Groovy Script snippet.

```
GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell();
sh.evaluate("\"abcd\".length() >= .34");
```

I am getting the following exceptions. The entire stack trace is mentioned below.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: >= @ line 1, column 17.
    "abcd".length() >= .34d
```

If I change `.34` to `0.34`, it works. However, because of some limitation, I won't be able to change the script content.
Any help to overcome will be appreciated.

I am getting the following exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: >= @ line 1, column 17.
    "abcd".length() >= .34d
                       ^
1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:584)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
at groovytest.Testtest.main(Testtest.java:18)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Groovy snippet is incorrect - Groovy does not support notation without leading zero in case of decimal numbers smaller than `1.0`. If you try to compile following expression directly using `groovyc`:

```
"abcd".length() >= .34
```

compilation will fail with error like:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
test.groovy: 2: Unexpected input: '.' @ line 2, column 20.
   "abcd".length() >= .34
                      ^

1 error
```

Java supports such notation, however Groovy from `2.x` up to `3.0.0-alpha-3` version does not support it.

### Solid solution

Fix the input Groovy code snippet to contain only a valid and compile-ready code. Any invalid Groovy statements or expressions will lead to failures and compilation errors.

> ### Workaround: add leading zeros with `replaceAll()` method
>
> The only way to compile such incorrect snippet is to replace all  `.\d+` *(dots followed by at least one space and ended with a number)* with  `0.$1`. Consider following example:
>
> ```groovy
> def snippet = "\"abcd\".length() >= .34; \"efgh\".length() >= .22; \"xyz\".length() >= 0.11;"
>
> println snippet.replaceAll(' \\.(\\d+)', ' 0.$1')
> ```
>
> It adds `0` to all decimal numbers where leading zero is missing. Running this example prints following output to the console:
>
> ```
> "abcd".length() >= 0.34; "efgh".length() >= 0.22; "xyz".length() >= 0.11;
> ```
>
> If you pass such modified snippet to `GroovyShell.evaluate()` method it will run with no errors.
>
> Of course this is not a rock-solid solution and it is just a way to automatically fix some of the syntax errors introduced in the code snippet. There are some corner cases where this workaround may cause some side effects, you have to be aware of it.

Comment: Thank you Szymon. What you mentioned is known to me already. Since there is limitation of editing of the contents, I am not able to programmatically edit. 
Also wanted to know what could be the limitation is Groovy that demands a leading 0 for decimals < 1.0

Comment: @user353949 But you execute `sh.evaluate(snippet)` or not? If you call `sh.evaluate(snippet)` than you can modify the input. If not then you have to request fixing Groovy snippet when it gets created. I don't see any other way of fixing it - the root of your problem is that Groovy compiler receives a code that cannot be compiled and there is no other way than fixing the code that way or another.

Comment: You could also extend `GroovyShell` with your own class and override `evaluate(String code)` method to replace all ` .\d+` with ` 0.$1` and then use this custom GroovyShell implementation. But this is actually the same solution as suggested in the answer - if you can provide custom GroovyShell then most probably you can modify the input for the regular GroovyShell while you're calling the `evaluate()` method.

Comment: Let's assume that we get a snippet sample as ".123 asdf".length() > .15; The problem here with regex substitution is tricky and it will fail as per your example as it will substitute .123 as 0.123. Is there a way to solve the issue by taking care of this type of corner cases?

Comment: @user353949 It wont replace `".123 asdf"` with `"0.123 asdf"` because the pattern used in `replaceAll` expects at least one space before `.`. Of course in case of `" .123 asdf"` it will end up with `"0.123 asdf"`. This is not a bulletproof solution, but your real problem is that you have to deal with Groovy snippets that don't even compile.

Comment: Thank you Szymon for your suggestion. Currently I opened a bug on the groovy jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8678. 
Based on the course of resolution of the bug, I will devise strategy to handle the isssue.